# How i can join 2 queries to display in 1 table

Tags: sql-server

I have 2 queries, they are almost the same, they return the same number of columns.

I want to create a stored procedure to get just 1 table based in 2 dates and 1 parameter.

```
select 
    Datepart(minute, created_at) as minuto,  
    avg(salida_1) as 'salida_1' 
from 
    salida_a 
where 
    created_at between '27/01/2020 04:00:00' and '27/01/2020 05:00:00' 
    and id_linea = 6 
group by 
    datepart(minute, created_at) 
order by 
    minuto       


select 
    Datepart(minute, created_at) as minuto, 
    avg(entrada_1) as 'entrada_1' 
from 
    entrada_a 
where 
    created_at between '27/01/2020 04:00:00' and'27/01/2020 05:00:00' 
    and id_linea = 6 
group by 
    datepart(minute, created_at) 
order by 
    minuto
```

Each query returns

```
"minuto0","entrada_1"
```

Other query

```
"minuto1","salida_1"
```

I want a single table like this

```
"minuto0","entrada_1","minuto1","salida_1"
```

or this

```
"minuto0","entrada_1","salida_1"
```

help

Comment: Assuming the two results have identical columns and datatypes, you can use a UNION ALL.  For example  Select ....  Union ALL Select ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an alternative to my union/conditional agg you can use a join. This might be easier to understand for you:

Take your existing query and turn them into cte:

```
WITH s as (
  select Datepart(minute, created_at) as minuto,  avg(salida_1) as 'salida_1' from salida_a where created_at between '27/01/2020 04:00:00' and '27/01/2020 05:00:00' and id_linea = 6 group by datepart(minute, created_at)
),      
E as (
  select Datepart(minute, created_at) as minuto, avg(entrada_1) as 'entrada_1' from entrada_a where created_at between '27/01/2020 04:00:00' and'27/01/2020 05:00:00' and id_linea = 6 group by datepart(minute, created_at)
)

SELECT 
  COALESCE(e.minuto, s.minuto) as minuto,
  S.salida_1,
  E.entrada_1
FROM
  s FULL OUTER JOIN e ON s.minuto = e.minuto
ORDER BY minuto
```

It takes your two queries and joins them so they are on one row, it uses either the minuto from s or e, then the value from each table. If there is a minuto in s of 1 and table e doesn't have a minuto of 1 then the avg from e will be null. If you want it to be 0 instead, use coalesce again to give a 0 instead of null:

```
COALESCE(e.entrada_1, 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

Put them together with union then split them apart with conditional aggregation

```
select
  Datepart(minute, created_at) as minuto, 
  avg(case when type = 's' then n end) as salida_1,
  avg(case when type = 'e' then n end) as entrada_1
from
  (
    select 's' as type, created_at, id_linea, salida_1 as n from salida_a 
    union all
    select 'e' as type, created_at, id_linea, entrada_1 as n from entrada_a 
  )
where 
  created_at between '27/01/2020 04:00:00' and '27/01/2020 05:00:00' and 
  id_linea = 6 
group by
  datepart(minute, created_at)
order by minuto
```

The union will take he two tables and combine their columns into one list of values. We have a constant e or s to track which table the data came from and we will need to use it later. We only select the columns we need

When the data has gone from two table into one we group and average it. We look at the type E or S, and use case when to provide the value for entrada column only when type is E. This means that type S values are made null in entrada column and so on. Because avg function doesn't include nulls only the average of the entrada data is calculated

Comment: OH thank you so much, it works so fine :O but i  have an issue when using "isnull()"

the colums, except "minuto" gets in blank, i mean without column name, "salida_1" "entrada_1" :/

Comment: You'll need to show table data that reproduces this; I can't quite understand what you mean

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO! You can do this with a UNION statement, but you will need all columns to be the same name. I suggest adding a "type" column to differentiate:

```
SELECT DATEPART(minute, [created_at]) AS [minuto]
     , [type] = 'salida'
     , AVG([salida_1]) AS avg
FROM salida_a
WHERE [created_at] BETWEEN '27/01/2020 04:00:00' AND '27/01/2020 05:00:00'
      AND [id_linea] = 6
GROUP BY DATEPART(minute, [created_at])
ORDER BY [minuto]
UNION ALL
SELECT DATEPART(minute, [created_at]) AS [minuto]
     , [type] = 'entrada'
     , AVG([entrada_1]) AS avg
FROM entrada_a
WHERE [created_at] BETWEEN '27/01/2020 04:00:00' AND '27/01/2020 05:00:00'
      AND [id_linea] = 6
GROUP BY DATEPART(minute, [created_at])
ORDER BY [minuto];
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **CROSS JOIN**

```
SELECT * 
FROM entrada_a CROSS JOIN 
     salida_a
```

[More Info](https://www.essentialsql.com/cross-join-introduction/)